# How to make android.net.Uri encode & between query parameters to %26

Tags: android

I have a Android app that needs to launch a web brower with a URL containing a query string. I build my Uri like this:

```
    Uri uri = builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("ids.example.com")
            .appendPath("account")
            .appendPath("login")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "seglaren")
            .appendQueryParameter("scope", "openid email name")
            .build();
```

and pass it to the browser using:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            startActivity(intent);
```

This launches the browser with the following URL:

https://ids.example.com/account/login?client_id=seglaren&scope=openid%20email%20name

The problem here is that the server I am calling does not accept this URL: it requires the separator between the query parameters to be encoded to "%26" instead of just "&". So it would need to be:

https://ids.example.com/account/login?client_id=seglaren%26scope=openid%20email%20name

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `.appendQueryParameter()` you can use `.encodedQuery()`.

`encodedQuery()` will be treated as if it is already encoded, thus not encoding it again. So you may insert your own string as you wish like in the example below.

```
String params = "client_id=seglaren%26scope=openid%20email%20name";

Uri uri = new Uri.Builder().scheme("https")
        .authority("ids.artdatabanken.se")
        .appendPath("account")
        .appendPath("login")
        .encodedQuery(params)
        .build();
```

You may use string concatenation or a `StringBuilder` to make the `String params` dynamic if you don't want to keep it hardcoded.

Result

```
"https://ids.artdatabanken.se/account/login?client_id=seglaren%26scope=openid%20email%20name"
```

Note that androids Uri.Builder is doing the correct thing by adding `&`to the parameter. So the API you're using probably has a bug if it requires `%26`.